# TypeError: expected a character buffer object ITS SO ANNOYING

Tags: python

This is what it says on the interpreter...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    nth_term_rule(list_a)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\Python 2.7 Functions Pack 1\nth_term_rule.py", line 5, in nth_term_rule
    f.write(n)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

This is really bugging me, I'm currently in the middle of the nth term rule function for my function pack and I'm attempting to make sure the sequence is steady - if not the nth term rule would be wrong. So I'm trying to append a text file that will have every number in the list in it. Then the interpreter will go through each number, making sure the difference between it and the next one is the same as difference as the previous numbers.

Unfortunately it comes up with the error above and I don't know why.

Here is my code if it helps...

```
def nth_term_rule(a):
  for n in a:
    str(n)
    f = open("C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\Python 2.7 Functions Pack 1\Numbers.txt","a")
    f.write(n)
    f.close()
  if a[0] - a[1] == a[len(a)-2] - a[len(a)-1]: 
    b=a[1] - a[0]
    c=a[0] - b
    return (b,'n + ',c)
  else:
    return ("Error.")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of `str()`:

```
str(n)
```

`str()` **returns** the new string, you want to assign this back to `n`:

```
n = str(n)
```

You probably want to avoid re-opening the  file each loop iteration; just open it *once*:

```
filename = r"C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\Python 2.7 Functions Pack 1\Numbers.txt"
with open(filename, "a") as f:
    for n in a:
        f.write(str(n) + \n)
```

This adds a few more things:

- Using the file as a context manager (with the `with` statement) makes sure that it is closed again automatically, when the block ends.
- Using a raw string literal (`r'...'`) prevents `\` being interpreted as an escape sequence. That way filenames that start with a `t` or `n` or `r`, etc. are not interpreted as special. See [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for more info.
- I assumed you probably wanted to have newlines between your values when written to the file.